# Datasift multiple thread in same connection

Tags: twitter, streaming, live-streaming

We are trying out an option of having multiple parallel thread meaning multiple consuming for different set of keywords by establishing single connection. Is it possible or should we establish new connection if we want to consume another set of data? Can anyone guide on this

Regards,
Balaji D

Answer (score 0):

This is documented on DataSift's [Multiple Streaming](http://dev.datasift.com/docs/streaming-api/multiple-streams) docs page. Some of the official [API Client Libraries](https://github.com/datasift) also support multi-streaming over WebSockets.